# REST urls not found with NGINX + FastCGI + Mono .ASMX

Tags: json, rest, nginx

I've got an Nginx REST service hanged at http://vps264757.ovh.net:8080/suma.asmx
Got same service hanged at same url, but port 8081, with mono xsp4, that it's all working properly.

When I try to use Nginx's in a REST way (i.e; ...8080/suma.asmx/test or ...8080/suma.asmx/sumaop?a=1&b=2) Nginx returns to me a 404 not found. As told, directly suma.asmx works properly and as well I can retrieve correctly wsdl from it with ...8080/suma.asmx?wsdl

Xsp4 on port 8081 works properly at all it's features (http://vps264757.ovh.net:8081/suma.asmx/sumaop?a=1&b=2 returns a correct xml with the sum). So, then, I understand it's a problem how nginx pass the REST uri to Fastcgi, or how Fastcgi parses this parameters.

I had really searched a lot and tried a lot of config combinations (using diferent regex, fastcgi_split_pathinfo, using proxy_pass instead of fastcgi_pass, etc,...) , but always with same 404 result when using REST access.

My current Nginx sites-available/default conf (simplest one) :

```
server {
   listen 8080;
   server_name vps264757.ovh.net;

   location ~ / {
     fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

My fastcgi_params it's the default one, just changing

```
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO ""; (I had used as well $fastcgi_path_info as value),
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

The execution of Fastcgi backend server it's no more than

`fastcgi_mono_server4 /applications=/:/home/_testjson /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9001`

Please, if you can give me a clue about what's happening,

Comment: You need to split the URI (e.g. with [`fastcgi_split_pathinfo`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_split_path_info)). So what regular expression did you try? Please update your question.

Comment: Hello Richard, now I'm trying with  location /(.*) { fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+)(/.+)$; (...) }, but I think it's parsing for example /suma.asmx/anything to /suma.asmx  all the cases.

Comment: now using location ~ { root /home/_testjson/;  fastcgi_split_path_info ^\/(.+\.asmx)\/(.*); (...) } and although it separates correcty first & second capture group, got this answer when trying (...)/suma.asmx/test 500 No Application found, Request path : suma.asmx ; physical path : home/_testjsonsuma.asmx, when I supose physical path should be /home/_testjson/suma.asmx.